# ZKTeco, and how to connect to the device

Tags: c#, .net

My efforts to connect to the ZKTeco device for access by key card goes unsuccessful for couple of days now. I am using .dll file that came with the device zkemkeeper.dll, add the reference in my simple .NET console API.

This my simple code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        zkemkeeper.CZKEM machineObj = new zkemkeeper.CZKEM();

        var status = machineObj.Connect_Net("Device IP", 4370);

        Console.WriteLine(status);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

As you can see its just Connect_Net("Device IP", 4370) that does all the work, but for some case I keep getting false for status value.

Can someone help, thank you.

Comment: Is that connecting over an TCP/IP network? Is 4370 the port?

Comment: which device did u used. provide us model number?

Comment: @rene Yes thats the port number

Comment: @ershoaib it's ACP-200

Comment: If you start a command prompt and run `telnet ipaddress.of.device.here 4370` does it connect? (You might have to install telnet first or use any other telnet client, like putty). Alternatively run a networksniffer like wireshark so see if there is network traffic to or from that device IP address, at all.

Comment: @rene I have installed telnet, and was able to connect to the device, I can also ping it successfully. So the device work and is online, but still when I try to connect from my console application it wont connect.

Comment: try to turn off your windows firewall and try again. may be your port 4370 blocked by firewall

Answer (score 1):

The default IP address is 192.168.1.124

Are you able to ping successfully? If not check your network settings. Also note a crossover cable or switch is required.

Are you able to connect with the provided Access software?

Comment: I can ping and connect with the provided software, from there I also got the port and the IP address. Device is in my local network.

Comment: device_ip should not be in quotes? it should be the actual ip address - or a string variable containing the ip address

Comment: its I string variable, yes

Comment: So should not be in quotes, for example my code for connection is: ConnectAttempt = FP_Device.Connect_Net(IP_Address, Port);

Comment: I just did not share the ip but this is how it actually looks 
machineObj.Connect_Net("192.168.15.241", 4370)

Comment: What does your object declaration look like? mine is private zkemkeeper.CZKEM FP_Device = new zkemkeeper.CZKEM(); if you message me your email I will send my working code

Comment: can you pass it here please, I have created a public interface and inherited  IZKEM, _IZKEMEvents_Event, so when I declare my object it looks like this, zkemkeeper.CZKEM machineObj = new zkemkeeper.CZKEM()

Comment: we transferred it instead: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/eaca349480eb88f9757f8270da6551fe20180926094159/7ce69990e2dd6161b4f2edbd1fa2975920180926094159/85f32c

Comment: Thank you, I have started your project but it's obviously not the coding problem since it's still not connected.